# HQL function to extract rows with field contains only number

Tags: regex, hibernate, hql, isnumeric

I've have a little issue to expose:

I want to extract from an entity, suppose its name "CustomerDetail" all rows where a specific field (code) has only numeric characters.

In HQL doesn't exist ISNUMERIC() function like Sql Server, and the possibility to apply regex function.

A possible solution is the following:

```
SELECT C
FROM CustomerDetail C
WHERE C.code NOT LIKE '%A%'
AND C.code NOT LIKE '%B%'
```

and so on repeating this condition overall alfabetical letter and special characters.

I think this is a poor solution, with a low level of performance (enormous number of LIKE)

Please, can you advice me a more smart solution?

Thank you in advance

P.S. My application is multi DBMS so I can't use SQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Major edit:
My bad, I mistook the just working function isNumeric() for a HQL function which is wrong. 
According to the [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) HQL supports database scalar functions - and SQLServer (on which I tested) has an isNumeric() function.

I see two options now:

Option 1:
You can write different HQLs for different databases which utilizes the build in functions like isNumeric() on SQLServer (but that's a huge step back in terms of "write once run everywhere")

Option 2:
Write for every database you want to be compliant with a custom function in SQL and register it with the same name in your dialect.

I know, both options aren't terrific but I can't think of any other way to get it working.

Comment: Dear, HQL has'n got isNumeric (as I've written in my question)

Comment: Have you TRIED my solution (incl. the `= 1`)? Because, like I've written in my answer - it works...

Comment: Before I write a question... I try my code. This is chapter 14 of HQL: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html Show allowed functions.

Answer (score 0):

Solution1:

```
 (CAST( value_to_check AS DECIMAL) IS NOT NULL)
```

Solution2 (you can extend it to check even hexadecimal numbers):

```
 ((size(SPLIT(value_to_check, "0"))-1) +
 (size(SPLIT(value_to_check, "1"))-1) +
 (size(SPLIT(value_to_check, "2"))-1) +
 (size(SPLIT(value_to_check, "3"))-1) +
 (size(SPLIT(value_to_check, "4"))-1) +
 (size(SPLIT(value_to_check, "5"))-1) +
 (size(SPLIT(value_to_check, "6"))-1) +
 (size(SPLIT(value_to_check, "7"))-1) +
 (size(SPLIT(value_to_check, "8"))-1) +
 (size(SPLIT(value_to_check, "9"))-1) = LENGTH(value_to_check))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).